# How to think recursively about `msort` function

Tags: haskell, recursion

These questions have to do more about how to think recursively in general, but I will take a specific example to illustrate.

Graham Hutton explains the function `mSort` in the video:

https://youtu.be/I9S61BYM9_4?t=2089

So, at the specific point I linked in the video, the professor says:

> And here, I have two sorted lists:

```hs
msort :: [Int] -> [Int] 
msort []  = [] 
msort [x] = [x] 
msort xs  =      (msort ys) (msort zs)
    where
        (ys, zs) = halve xs
```

and highlights the expressions `(msort ys)` and `(msort zs)`. Then, he adds the word `merge` in front of those expressions.

```hs
msort :: [Int] -> [Int] 
msort []  = msort [] 
msort [x] = msort [x] 
msort xs  = merge (msort ys) (msort zs)
    where
        (ys, zs) = halve xs
```

To me, it seems there are some assumptions, similar to assumptions in logic, like "if this hypothetical scenario is true, then (some statements are deduced)". Those are useful to think about recursion, but have nothing to do with the evaluation of the recursive function. So, my questions are:

- How can he speak about `msort ys` when `msort` at a point where it is not fully defined ?
- Everything written there doesn't have any magical meaning, of course. But are the chosen words only helpful to reason about the function? I am asking since he speaks about `msort ys` is a "sorted list". He uses the past tense.
- Does this assume `halve` is going to be defined in a sensible way ? Again, `halve` is just a name.

I apologize if these are really basic questions. It's something I've just started wondering recently.

Comment: I took a crack at answering your question, but if the answer doesn't help, are you confused about the *technical* mechanisms that allow us to write functions that call themselves before they are fully defined?  Like, how does the computer actually *do* this?

Comment: Thank you so much. Your answer helps a lot. I am not wondering about the technical mechanism, but instead the conventions used to communicate and think about this kind of things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These questions are "basic" but in the sense that they are fundamental to understanding functional languages and the concept of recursive programs, not in the sense that they are easy or obvious to answer.

The similarity to assumptions in logic is not entirely coincidental.  The definition of `msort` given by Hutton is related to proof by induction in mathematical logic.  In a usual sort of mathematical inductive proof, we prove that something holds for a small "base case" (e.g., holds for `n=0`), and then we prove that *if* something holds for any arbitrary sized case (e.g., any particular `n`), it holds for a "slightly bigger" case (e.g., for `n+1`).  From this, we are able to conclude that it holds for all cases (e.g., for all values of `n>=0`).

Here, we prove a property for a couple of small cases (e.g., it's easy to sort the empty list, and it's easy to sort the one-element list), and then we prove that *if* we can sort two lists of roughly length `n/2` (e.g., `msort ys` and `msort zs`), *then* we can sort a list of length `n` (`msort xs`), and we conclude by induction that lists of any size can be sorted.  There are lots of details to fill in here, like what it means to take half the length of an odd-length list to get two lists that are "roughly" half the length, etc., but this is the general idea.

It's maybe worth pointing out that, even though part of the mathematical proof takes the form "if we assume that lists of size 15 can be sorted, then we can sort a list of size 30", it is not necessary that we assume lists of size 15 can be sorted in order to use this proof.  The proof works because the premises "a list of size 1 can be sorted" and "assuming a list of size n can be sorted, then a list of size n*2 can be sorted" allows us to conclude that all lists of size equal to powers of two can be sorted (and with some minor modifications to this proof, we can show that lists of any size can be sorted too).  The "assumption" is part of the formal structure of the valid proof, not an assumption we need to make for the proof to be valid.

In a way, this is true of the recursive function `msort`.  The magic of modern functional languages is that `msort` *can* be used within `msort` before it is "fully defined".  That's because we don't need to show we can define `msort` for, say a list of size 15.  We only need to show that we can define `msort` for a list of size 30 *in terms* of `msort` for a list of size 15, and as long as we add a couple of base cases that don't depend on `msort` (e.g., lists of size zero or one are sorted directly), the definition of `msort` -- like the mathematical proof of induction -- works fine.

When Sutton talks about `msort ys` being sorted in the past tense, he's running up against difficulties with matching English tenses to the meaning of recursive functions.  At compile time, `msort ys` is just a reference to a function that is in the process of being defined, but that's the magic of recursive functions -- part of the process of defining them involves calling the function that's in the middle of being defined.  At runtime, the tenses are accurate.  When you run `msort [4,3,2,1]`, it will invoke `msort [4,3]` which will sort the list into `[3,4]` and `msort [2,1]`, which will sort the list into `[1,2]`, and these sorted (past tense) values will be available to be `merge`d into a final result `[1,2,3,4]`.

I'm not sure I understand why you aren't sure you understand `halve` -- yes, this assumes that `halve` is going to be defined in some sensible way that matches its name.  But, since `halve` doesn't depend on `msort` or on `halve`, it doesn't pose the same philosophical questions as `msort`.  If it helps, pretend `halve` is defined as:

```
halve xs = (take n xs, drop n xs) where n = length xs `div` 2
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! I’ll carefully read your explanation tomorrow and see if I can fully understand it before asking you.

Comment: I could understand why the use of past tense is appropriate. I will ask you a couple of things, if you don’t mind. Why do you say: “if we can sort two lists of roughly length `n/2`”? How does that connect with the actual recursive definition ? Is the action of sorting related to the application of `mSort` to `ys`?

Comment: The recursive definition is `msort xs = merge (msort ys) (msort zs)`, and -- if `xs` is of even length` -- both `ys` and `zs` are half the length of `xs` because of the definition of `halve`.  So, all I'm saying is that we can sort a list of any length `n` by sorting two lists each of length `n/2`.  That is, *if* we know how to sort lists of length `n/2`, then using this definition we must *also* know how to sort lists of length `n`.

Comment: Thank you. And where does the assumption "if we know how to sort lists of length `n/2` appear ? Is a common convention in a recursion definition that the mere act of writing, for example, that `msort ys` is the assumption that I can know how to sort `ys` ?

Comment: The second issue is: at the point where Hutton highlights `msort ys` and `msort zs`, `merge` isn't written anywhere. So, that's why I think people who know how to write recursive functions assume a common convention; that is, even the function is not fully defined, the mere act of writing `msort ys` is the assumption that I _know_ how to sort `ys`. Does that make sense ?

Comment: Hi, @K.A.Buhr. I hope you are doing fine. After these months, I realized something new revisiting your answer. There is nothing special about `halve` function. Could be a function that returns a pairs of lists where the first component is the head, and the second one is the tail of the list. It is just that merge needs two lists to work. Is that OK ?

Comment: Yes, the general ideas all work the same if you replace `halve` with any function that breaks a list into two smaller lists, so replacing `halve` with a function that returns the head (as a singleton list) and the tail would work.  From a practical point of view, the resulting sort would not be nearly as efficient as one that used a proper `halve` function, but from a theoretical point of view, the recursive concepts would be the same -- we would be saying that we can sort a 100-element list of we can sort a 99-element list and a 1-element list, and so one.

Comment: Thank you ! Did you mean that we can sort a 100 element list, if we know how to sort a 99-element list and a 1-element list?

Comment: Yes, there were a couple of typos.  It should read "... we can sort a 100-element list if we can sort a 99-element list and a 1-element list, and so on."